# How to display image on URL bar

Tags: css, styles, favicon

I want to display an image and some text on the URL bar of browser.

I am able to display an image by using tag `<link type="image/x-icon" href="../../images/iconFav.bmp" rel="shortcut icon" />` but could not show text beside the image.

What actually I wanted to do is just like stackoverflow shows an image on URL bar, I would like to show an image and few text :)
Otehr example would be to have a look at `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/` which displays an image and `facebook.com` beside that image on URL bar

Comment: Are you asking how to set a favicon or something else?

Comment: I am able to set the favicon and my browser location bar also shows the fav icon. But if u look at the facebook link provided, it also shows some text beside favicon. Wanted to know how to show that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that text appears if the site is secure and verified by some organisation. But I was able to display the image on location bar by using `<link type="image/x-icon" href="../../images/iconFav.bmp" rel="shortcut icon"/>`

Answer (score 4):

That text (displayed next to the favicon.ico) is the HTML [title element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp):

```
<html><head><title>Your text here</title></head></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

That favicon isn't displaying because BMP is not a supported favicon file format. For the best support use an ICO file. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support

You can use [Favicon.co.uk](http://www.favicon.co.uk/) to convert your image to ICO format if you like

Then link to it like this:

```
 <link href="/location/of/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

Then for the title use `<title>Your Title</title>` inside the `<head>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on favicons. Also ensure your using the right doctype with the right fav icon link. You need to convert your favicon to a ico file with a converter: I prefer this one: http://www.prodraw.net/favicon/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're referring to is the SSL extended validartion information. Modern browsers display sites running under HTTPS with the domain in blue or green (depending on the type of SSL certificate purchased).

More details about extended validation are available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate but effectively it's not possible to control the text - it's either the domain of your site e.g. facebook.com or the name of your organisation e.g. "PayPal Inc." and requires an SSL certificate to be purchased and is only shown on your website when browsed using SSL.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done.  On https sites, some browsers will put things beside the image (the site name) to show that you are visiting the site in a secured way, but there is no way that a programmer can control this, it's built into the browser.  You can control the favicon image, that's all.